# Is ggplot2 geom_smooth broken or is something wrong with my system?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I have been using our institution's virtual computing version of R/RStudio.  I have never had a problem with ggplot2 on this system before.  However, starting today, when I make a graph including geom_smooth, the fit line is completely wrong.  I checked the documentation and ran one of their examples, and it still happened:

```
require(tidyverse)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)
```

[image: ggplot2 geom_smooth broken?]

Does anyone know what might be happening here?  How can I fix this?  The version of R is 4.3.1, the version of RStudio is 2023.6.1.524, and the version of ggplot2 is 3.4.3.

EDIT 1: Here is the output from `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.3.so;  LAPACK version 3.8.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: America/Chicago
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggprism_1.0.4      neuroCombat_1.0.13 broom_1.0.5        lubridate_1.9.2    forcats_1.0.0      stringr_1.5.0      dplyr_1.1.2       
 [8] purrr_1.0.2        readr_2.1.4        tidyr_1.3.0        tibble_3.2.1       ggplot2_3.4.3      tidyverse_2.0.0    emmeans_1.8.8     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0    farver_2.1.1        fastmap_1.1.1       TH.data_1.1-2       digest_0.6.33       rpart_4.1.19       
 [7] estimability_1.4.1  timechange_0.2.0    lifecycle_1.0.3     cluster_2.1.4       survival_3.5-5      magrittr_2.0.3     
[13] compiler_4.3.1      rlang_1.1.1         Hmisc_5.1-0         tools_4.3.1         utf8_1.2.3          data.table_1.14.8  
[19] knitr_1.43          labeling_0.4.2      htmlwidgets_1.6.2   plyr_1.8.8          multcomp_1.4-25     abind_1.4-5        
[25] BiocParallel_1.34.2 foreign_0.8-84      withr_2.5.0         nnet_7.3-19         grid_4.3.1          googledrive_2.1.1  
[31] fansi_1.0.4         xtable_1.8-4        colorspace_2.1-0    scales_1.2.1        MASS_7.3-60         cli_3.6.1          
[37] mvtnorm_1.2-3       rmarkdown_2.24      generics_0.1.3      rstudioapi_0.15.0   modelr_0.1.11       tzdb_0.4.0         
[43] DBI_1.1.3           splines_4.3.1       parallel_4.3.1      cellranger_1.1.0    matrixStats_1.0.0   base64enc_0.1-3    
[49] vctrs_0.6.3         Matrix_1.6-1        sandwich_3.0-2      carData_3.0-5       car_3.1-2           hms_1.1.3          
[55] rstatix_0.7.2       Formula_1.2-5       htmlTable_2.4.1     glue_1.6.2          codetools_0.2-19    stringi_1.7.12     
[61] gtable_0.3.3        sensemakr_0.1.4     munsell_0.5.0       pillar_1.9.0        htmltools_0.5.6     R6_2.5.1           
[67] dbplyr_2.3.3        evaluate_0.21       lattice_0.21-8      haven_2.5.3         backports_1.4.1     googlesheets4_1.1.1
[73] gargle_1.5.2        Rcpp_1.0.11         nlme_3.1-162        gridExtra_2.3       checkmate_2.2.0     mgcv_1.8-42        
[79] xfun_0.40           fs_1.6.3            zoo_1.8-12          pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: Looks like `mpg` included with ggplot2.

Comment: My first guess is that `geom_smooth()` is overwritten. Does replacing that line with `ggplot2::geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)` give you the expected result?

Comment: Works for me: ggplot2 3.4.3, R 4.3.0, RStudio 2023.06.1+524. So really similar set up to yours. Can you add the session info from when you ran this code?

Comment: I tried ```ggplot2::geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)``` and got the same result.  As for session info, I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you tell me how to get the needed info?  Thanks!

Comment: `sessionInfo()` and paste the output to your question. Does this still happen if you run this in a fresh session? Have you tried reinstalling `ggplot2`?

Comment: fyi, on R-4.2.3 and ggplot2_3.4.2, it works https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbcfO.png

Comment: I edited my question to add sessionInfo() output.  I restarted R and cleared the environment and it is still happening.  There may be a way to do a deeper reset on the virtual environment but I'd have to look into it.  I have not tried reinstalling ggplot2 yet, can try that.